# como incrementar +1, cada vez que llame a la funcion RANGE() sin llamar constantemente a NEXT()?

Tags: python

Saludos como podria llamar a esta funcion, e incrementar +1 sin tener que repetir la llamada a NEXT() cada vez que quiera incrementar el numero. Alguna idea?

```
 def numero():
    inicio = 0
    final = 20
    for rango in range(inicio, final):
        yield rango 
    
    
valor = numero()
    
print(next(valor))
print(next(valor))
print(next(valor))
print(next(valor))
```

Comment: Entiendo que eso es parte de usar `yield`. Probablemente no sea el camino para lograr lo que quieres.

Comment: alguna idea en mente?

Comment: Si pudieras explicar para qué lo quieres se podría pensar en una solución más específica. Darte una solución genérica puede implicar crear una clase o escribir más código del que realmente sería necesario para tu caso particular.

Comment: itera valor con un ciclo for `for i in valor:`,  Los generadores son en realidad iteradores, pero sólo permiten ser iterados una vez. Esto se debe a que no almacenan todos los valores en memoria, sino que los van generando al vuelo. Pueden ser usados de dos formas diferentes, iterándolos con un bucle o con una funcion.

Comment: @Mateo poder insertar dentro de un rango, ejemplo: numero1 = 5, numero2 = 10 donde cada vez que llame a la funcion, incremente +1 sin que haga lo siguiente 5,6,7,8,9 si no cada vez que llame a la funcion. +1 hasta cumplir el rango.

Comment: esta funcion esta dentro de  programación orientada a objetos @Mateo la saque para simplificarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tener que usar `next` forma parte de `yield`. La solución entonces no va por ahí.

Podrías usar una variable en la que guardes el rango y la posición actual.

Algo así:

```
rango = range(0, 10)
pos = -1

def numero():
    global pos
    pos += 1
    return rango[pos]

print(numero()) # 0
print(numero()) # 1
print(numero()) # 2
print(numero()) # 3
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vygxLz1fwVYBRKdqGOgoGBpochXkFwOFdA25uFJS0xTySnNTi/I1NK24FIAgPSc/KTFHAagEzAUp1bZVMARzilJLSovywGblRwNlYrm4Cooy80o0YEZoksr//x8A).

---

Está forma tiene algunos inconvenientes. Como que las variables pueden ser modificadas fácilmente o podrías querer tener más de un rango a la vez.

Estos problemas los puedes solucionar poniendo el código en una clase. Por ejemplo:

```
class Rango:

    def __init__(self, inicio, fin):
        self.rango = range(inicio, fin)
        self.pos = -1
    
    def numero(self):
        self.pos += 1
        return self.rango[self.pos]
```

Al final ocupas más código y probablemente hubiera sido más simple seguir con el código original, usando la función `next`.

Comment: Saludos, si la variable del rango inicializa dentro de la clase, como has hecho con tu ejemplo, como podria pasarle estos valores (inicio, final) a travez de un texbox digitandolo? o un spinbox?

Comment: @wally Instancias la clase mediante `Rango(inicio, final)`.

Answer (score 0):

Como indicas que estas empleando POO y asumiendo que la función numero es un metodo de clase, quizas te funcione lo siguiente:

```python
class Sample():
    def __init__(self, inicio, fin, increment=0):
        self.inicio = inicio
        self.fin = fin
        self.counter = 0
        self.increment = increment
        
    def numero(self):
        for i in range(self.inicio, self.fin):
            self.counter += self.increment
            yield i
        
instance = Sample(inicio=0, fin=5, increment=5)
numero = instance.numero()

for i in numero:
    print(f"Numero {i} es {instance.counter}")
```

- Inicializamos la instancia de la clase con los valores del rango (inicio y fin), un factor de incremento que es 0 por defecto y un contador
- Hacemos de la función `numero` una función generadora empleando `range` y dentro del ciclo incrementamos la variable `counter` en base al factor de incremento.

Lo cual da el siguiente resultado:

```
Numero 0 es 5
Numero 1 es 10
Numero 2 es 15
Numero 3 es 20
Numero 4 es 25
```

Me indicas si es este tu enfoque o si me desenfoque =D.
Saludos!

Comment: No es por ser aguafiestas, pero básicamente acabas de recrear la clase `range` usando un `range`. Me refiero a que podrías haber usado directamente `for i in range(...):` en lugar de `for i in numero:`. Esto seguro de que podrías hacer la clase sin depender de `range` y te daría un punto.